# Why is 0 factorial is equal to 1 ??

Tags: factorial

Why is 0! Equal to 1? Can anyone can help to understand ? Please explain with discription

Comment: If you Google it, you will find thousands of results

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from $5! = 5*4*3*2*1$

Now if we go down one number to $4!$ essentially we divide $5!$ by $5.$

Following that logic going down to $3!$ we divide $4!$ by 4 keep doing this till $1!$. So to get $0!$ all we do is divide $1!$ by $1$